# Not able to type anything in intellij idea terminal latest version on Windows 10

Tags: intellij-idea, terminal, windows-10

I am using Intellij idea 14.1.3 latest community version. I am not able to type a single letter in the terminal. I am not getting whats the issue. Could anybody help me to solve the issue. [image]

[image]

Comment: I too am having this issue.

Comment: I am seeing this as well on Windows 10 GA.

Comment: I saw the same issue so as the other alternative I used the node.js command prompt.Open node.js command prompt then navigate to your project and use the command as in the terminal window in webstorm.

Answer (score 20):

This is tracked in JetBrains bug tracker here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-143300
Please vote for this issue.

There is a workaround which is to enable Legacy mode for the Windows shell.

To do so, open a command prompt window (`cmd.exe`), right click on the title, then select `Properties`. At the bottom, check `Use legacy console`. Confirm the dialog. Go back to the IDE and launch a new Terminal. It should work.

Comment: The other alternative is to use the node.js command prompt.Open node.js command prompt then navigate to your project and use the command as in the terminal window in webstorm.

Comment: Why does it have to be the node.js command prompt? Could you not use the regular cmd and navigate there? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem in IntelliJ while I was working on a gradle-jbehave project. My problem was I had created the project using commandline and had left the command prompt window open. The issue disappeared when I closed all the open  command prompt windows,
 ie:

1. I opened cmd.exe
2. created a mvn project using 
   "*mvn archetype:generate -Dfilter=org.jbehave:jbehave*"
3. then switching to the project root via cmd.exe
   "*mvn idea:idea*"
4. changed it to a gradle project by
   "*gradle init*"
5. Opened this project in intelliJ, everything looked good until I tried to build it via terminal
6. I closed the cmd.exe I opened in step1, and voila, everything started to work fine.

Comment: Thank you so much brodoll for the formatting. I am new to the forum and had a hard time figuring it out. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2):

(Linux:) A simple `Control + C` seems to help.

PS: No, that does **not** indicate that someone is just unable to quit a program that is running in the terminal. That is not the problem here.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I am currently using Linux and it works fine. Only issue is with Win10.

Comment: helps on Mac OS as well