# On windows 10, the console window does not accept keyboard input

Tags: java, intellij-idea, terminal

1. Install Windows 10 preview (stable build)
2. Install IU using the installer
3. Open a new Java project
4. Alt+F12 - a CMD console pops up
5. Try to type something in the console - nothing happens

(Intellij idea 14.1.3)

Answer (score 2):

Because collision keyboard shortcut keys between Windows 10 & IntelliJ IDEA.
**Solution:**
Change `Keyboard Shortcut` to what you want.
[image]

Comment: Hey there, do you know exactly which program on Windows 10 has the shortcut collision with Intellij for **Alt+F12**

Comment: I don't know. I see it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_keyboard_shortcuts (search keyword `F12`)

Comment: I figured out what it was on my system....Nvidia Geforce Experience (ShadowPlay)... See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39802124/intellij-idea-terminal-shortcut-not-working

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue. The only working solution for me was to switch to legacy console.

To do this you need to:

1. Start `cmd.exe`
2. Right click on the window title
3. Click **properties -> options**
4. Check *Use legacy console* at the bottom
5. Close `cmd.exe`, close all terminal windows in `ItelliJ`
6. Start new terminal in `IntelliJ` (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>)
7. Then it should work

You can also take a look at the issue in the `IntelliJ` tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-143300 or another post here [Not able to type anything in intellij idea terminal latest version on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30425857/not-able-to-type-anything-in-intellij-idea-terminal-latest-version-on-windows-10/31768422#31768422)