# Intellij Idea Terminal shortcut not working

Tags: intellij-idea, windows-10

I am currently using Intellij Idea 2016.2.4 and running on Windows 10. I have noticed that the **Alt+F12** command for opening the Terminal and the **Alt+F7** command for Finding Usages of a particular method have both stopped working.

I have tried the following:

- File -> Invalidate Caches and Restart
- Re-import project
- Change Keymap scheme
- Reinstall Intellij (no settings were kept)

It seems that **Windows 10** is somehow using the **Alt+F12** and **Alt+F7** key combinations for some other shortcut. Is this any way I can find out what program this key combination has been bound to?

Thanks!

Comment: If you downvote a question, leave an explanation as to why. Otherwise, no one can benefit or improve from your observation(s)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just found the source of the problem...

I am an avid gamer and my system runs on an Nvidia graphics card. As such I have **Nvidia GeForce Experience** (3.0.6.48) installed and it comes with **ShadowPlay**. However, **ShadowPlay** has some keybindings which conflict with **Intellij IDEA**, listed below:

- Alt+F7 - pauses/resumes broadcasting
- Alt+F12 - toggles FPS counter on/off

In previous versions of **Nvidia GeForce Experience**, you could access the **ShadowPlay** Tab and configure shortcut keybindings but, that panel has been removed in the latest version of **Nvidia GeForce Experience**

The solution is to either uninstall **Nvidia GeForce Experience** or diagnose why ShadowPlay is missing using online guides e.g. [Shadow Play Button is gone](https://www.reddit.com/r/pcgaming/comments/2mfonk/shadowplay_button_is_gone_in_geforce_experience/)

Link: [Nvidia Shadowplay Default Keybindings](https://www.reddit.com/r/nvidia/comments/2uyfo7/nvidia_shadowplay_default_keybindings_list/)

Comment: One can use http://hkcmdr.anymania.com/ to find which application has registered a global hotkey.

Comment: This was a really annoying issue. I was able to solve it by opening GeForce Experience --> click little triangle thingy in top right --> settings --> keybindings --> mapping them all to more obscure combinations.

Comment: You can also [disable the new Share Overlay functionality](http://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/4228/~/how-to-disable-the-geforce-experience-share-in-game-overlay) and leave GeForce Experience installed. In this case it will not hijack the `Alt+F#` keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Following on from @CorayThan, in the latest Expeience -> click little triangle thingy in top right (share your gaming moments) --> settings cog in the overlay --> Keyboard shortcuts --> Select the shortcut you wish to remap, it will go green, e.g. Select Alt F7, then press what keysyou want to use, e.g. Alt + Ctrl + Shift + F7 or whatever you want to map it to so that Alt F7 works again

Comment: In the latest GeForce Experience version I just had to do the following :
Settings --> Disable "In Game Overlay"

Comment: Anyone who uses JetBrains' ReSharper or Rider can also suffer from this

Answer (score 1):

You can view all the keyboard shortcuts for windows 10 here :https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12445/windows-keyboard-shortcuts

There does not seem to be any with F12